# Change font color in Django ModelChoiceField widget after selection made

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-crispy-forms

I have styled the font and font color for the select menu in my Django form using the widget. Is it possible to change the font color once a selection is made? For example, select menu text starts off white and after selection is made it turns green. I am using Crispy Form tags on the front end.

```py
    class FootballLineup(forms.ModelForm):

        class Meta:
            model = FootballContestEntry
            fields = ['qb']

        qb = forms.ModelChoiceField(label='',                               
                                    queryset=NFLPlayer.objects.filter(active=True, 
                                                                      position='QB'), 
                                    empty_label="Select Quarterback", 
                                    required=True)

        qb.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'text-center lineup-select marker'})
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. I went into dev tools to see how the crispy form select was rendered, got the id that was assigned to it and used basic js to change the class.

```py
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#id_qb').on("change", function () {
                    $(this).removeClass('orange');
                    $(this).addClass('text-light');
                });
            });
```